# Call method through method in parameter

Tags: java, lambda

How can I call a method that is passed on through a parameter in a method in Java 8?

Small example I have a method like that:

```
void output(String text) {
    System.out.println(text)
}
```

Now I want to pass that method to another class which should call `output` and set something for text. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a Java 8 method reference type solution or just any type of solution?

Comment: Well, I'm using Java 8, so I don't mind any kind of solution that works with Java 8 :) The key point is, that I want to use the method in another class and not in the same one.

Comment: Please, clarify your need, your comment is not the same as the question. Note : Reflection or maybe using a default method in an interface (could be... but doubt it).

Comment: @AxelH There are method references in Java. It seems like that is what he wants.

Comment: If you just want to call the method in another class, is there something that prevents you from doing it the normal way?

Comment: There is already an answer that is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class you want to pass the function to must take a parameter of type `Consumer<String>`. This class represents a function that takes a parameter of some type (`String` in this case), and has return type `void`. A `Consumer` has a method `accept` that takes the parameter and calls the function.

You can create you class like this:

```
class Test {
    Test(Consumer<String> consumer) {
        consumer.accept("This is a string!");
    }
}
```

Now, when you want to instantiate this class, you need to pass your function to it like this:

```
Test t = new Test(this::output);
```

The `::` notation is called a method reference. The `this` (before the colons) means that the method is located in the object you're in. It can be changed to, for example, `MyClass::output` if it is a static method on `MyClass`, or `myObject::output` if it is a method on the object `myObject`.

Comment: It only has to take a `String` and have return type `void`. The `this::` means that it located in the object you're in, but it can be changed to, for example, `MyClass::output` if it is a static method on `MyClass`, or `myObject::output` if it is a method on the object `myObject`.

Comment: You should edit your answer and add your comment into it.  Future searchers are more apt to read the answer than the comments

Comment: @CraigR8806 Will do. My comment was an answer to a now deleted comment.

Comment: Ahh I see, that makes more sense.

Comment: @CraigR8806 mine to be complete ;) Asked the question but understand myself just after I send it... How safe is it, is it GC safe ? the method reference of an instance will prevent the GC to collect the instance ? Well, I might document myself on this one, could be useful !

Comment: The method reference creates an object of type `Consumer` (although there might be optimizations under the hood). In the example, it will be eligible for GC after the constructor of `Test` has returned. I guess it acts like any other object.